# Why is Express app's use/all method not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is my express app:

```
var tty = require('tty.js');

var app = tty.createServer({
  shell: 'bash',
  port: 3001
});

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  next();
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    next();
});

app.listen();
```

My goal is to add a header to the response to allow cross-domain access. In theory, both the all and use method calls should take care of that, but neither of their function arguments is being called by the app at any point.

Comment: `tty.js` uses  `express`?

Comment: Can you try by following this order? app.use(), app.get() and then app.all()

Comment: tty.js adds express's methods to the returned tty object in lines 607 - 627 here: https://github.com/chjj/tty.js/blob/master/lib/tty.js. It does it in an error-prone way, and I think the cause of the problems is that the middle of the 3 statement uses getOwnProperties which doesn't return methods on the prototype (which is where I believe express's server methods are located).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an [middleware](http://expressjs.com/resources/middleware.html). It's done via use function, try to implement following way. And put it before all other functions:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you need to implement a middleware. In my case I did it by accesing to the part of the app that creates the Express server.

I can share with you some code, that will be of help:

```
var tty = require('./libs/tty/tty.js');
app = tty.createServer(conf)
//Routes
var User=require('./routes/user');
var Files=require('./routes/files');

app.use( bodyParser.json() );
app.use('/user',User);
app.use('/files',Files);
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers usually send pre-flight OPTIONS request for CORS connection. Check this [article](http://learntogoogleit.com/post/61327173902/cors-preflight-request-testing-in-curl).

You can handle OPTIONS request as below:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, accept, access-control-allow-origin');

    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) res.send(200);
    else next();
});
```

or use the [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) npm module:

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```

Check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/hankchiutw/97def36717c020578a0c) for complete js file.